# How to Pass an Array from a JSR223 Sampler to Another JSR223 Sampler?

Tags: jmeter

I just want to know how to pass an array from a JSR223 sampler to another JSR223 sampler. Note that the two JSR223 are just in the same thread. I had been searching and I cannot find the exact solution. I'm just a newbie in Jmeter, just searching for java codes etc. So here is the code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(response);

int size = json.records.size;
vars.put("intDashboardMeetingsCount", size);

def strMeetingsArray = new String[size];

if (size > 0) {
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        strMeetingsArray[i] = json.records.get(i).id;
    }
}
```

I already got the number of records in `intDashboardMeetingsCount`, and I just need to know how will I able to get the data of `strMeetingsArray[]`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `vars` shorthand, it stands for [JMeterVariables](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance so you should be able to use [`vars.putObject()`](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) function in order to add your `strMeetingsArray` to JMeter Variables and [`vars.getObject()`](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject-java.lang.String-) to retrieve it.

So in 1st JSR223 Sampler:

```
vars.putObject('somevar', strMeetingsArray)
```

in 2nd JSR223 Sampler:

```
def strMeetingsArray = vars.getObject('somevar')
```

More information: [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Anyway the `vars.put("intDashboardMeetingsCount", size)` has an error, since only String data type can be entered in the `vars.put()`, so I just converted it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use variables (vars) for a single thread. When you do a multi-thread test, you can use the properties (props).

Sample Variable Used Javascript  Code:

```
vars.put("myString","mysamplestring");
var getString= vars.get("myString");

var array = ['bilal','demir'];
vars.putObject("myArray",array);
var getArray = vars.getObject("myArray");

log.info( "*getString : {} *getArray :{} *firstItem: {} *length : {}" , getString, getArray, getArray.length, getArray[0]);
//output: *getString : mysamplestring *getArray :{0=bilal, 1=demir} *firstItem: bilal *length : 2
```

Sample Properties Used Javascript  Code:

```
var array = ['bilal','demir'];
props.put("myArray",array);
var getArray = props.get("myArray");

log.info( "getArray :{}  length : {}" , getArray, getArray.length);
//output: getArray :{0=bilal, 1=demir}  length : 2
```

For groovy change define variable code `var` to `def`